# Python2/3 give different answers to the same math operation...why? (calculating percent difference)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, math

Python 2 and Python 3 seem to arrive at different answers for the very simple math operation of finding percentage difference between two quantities.

For example:

```
# Python 2.7.10
>>> def percent_difference(qty1, qty2):
...     diff = max(qty1, qty2) - min(qty1, qty2)
...     print(diff)
...     percent = diff / ( (qty1 + qty2) / 2)
...     print(percent)
... 
>>> percent_difference(1, 2)
1
1

# Python 3.6.2

>>> def percent_difference(qty1, qty2):
...     diff = max(qty1, qty2) - min(qty1, qty2)
...     print(diff)
...     percent = diff / ( (qty1 + qty2) / 2)
...     print(percent)
... 
>>> percent_difference(1, 2)
1
0.6666666666666666
```

What's going on here?

(Python3 is correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Python2` and `Python3` treat the div operation for integers differently.

In `python3` the div operation will treat integers and floats the same:

```
2/3 = 1.5
2.0/3 = 1.5
2/3.0 = 1.5
2.0/3.0 = 1.5
```

In `python2` it will truncate the number after the floating points if both operands are integers:

```
2/3 = 1
2.0/3 = 1.5
2/3.0 = 1.5
2.0/3.0 = 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 changed the behaviour of the `/` operator. It used to depend on the used types (i.e. `integer / integer` is integer division, if one of the operands is a float you get float division).

The rationale for the change is explained in the Python Enhancement Proposal [PEP-0238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/#motivation):

> The correct work-around is subtle: casting an argument to float() is wrong if it could be a complex number; adding 0.0 to an argument doesn't preserve the sign of the argument if it was minus zero. The only solution without either downside is multiplying an argument (typically the first) by 1.0. This leaves the value and sign unchanged for float and complex, and turns int and long into a float with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Python that you want float output.
Try `percent_difference(1.0, 2.0)`